# Need help in $_GET

Tags: php

I have a php page like this

```
if($_GET){
    if($_GET['name'] && $_GET['number']){
        $name = $_GET['name'];
        $number = (int) $_GET['number'];
        echo "Got it!";
    } else {
        echo "Please give input!";
    }
} else {
    echo "Please give input!";
}
```

Now it works fine when there is no input is given. But if i give one input like `page.php?name=Something&number=0` it gives error `Undefined index: number`

And the value of number also can be 0.

This error doesn't look good. Now how can I get rid from this? Please help!

Comment: 0 in php is evaluated  in if as false,use isset function

Comment: Use  `isset`. You also shouldn't have display errors on in production.

Comment: Thanks, it's now working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use isset to check

also check it explicitly like $_GET['name']!='' and dont print or store whatever you get from get and post etc.. if you are storing to database using mysli_real_escape_string.  and if you are outputting to browser use htmlspecialchars

```
    if(isset($_GET)){
        if(isset($_GET['name']) && $_GET['name']!='' && isset($_GET['number']) && $_GET['number']!=''){
            $name = $_GET['name'];
            $number = (int) $_GET['number'];
            echo "Got it!";
        } else {
            echo "Please give input!";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Please give input!";
```

Comment: @ chris85 bro i dont understand could you please explain? trim is for removing the whitespace. how it will help here.

Comment: Thanks for your help! It's now working. And yes I'm using htmlspecialchars.

Comment: happy to see your comment

Comment: The space between the `@` and username takes out the notification. I retracted my comment because it was specific to `empty`, like i retracted my comment about using the `isset` rather than the direct comparison.